# Windows-Services Memory Leak

Tags: windows-7, memory, services, memory-leaks

I have a problem with a few services that take up more and more ram. I usually let the computer on without restarts and after a while some of the services take very big chunks.

The services are split into two svchost processes.

[image]

Here they take up 100 MB each, but this goes up to over 500 MB each.
The corresponding services are:

**1st svchost process**

- `EventSystem` (COM+ Event System)
- `FontCache` (Windows Font Cache Service)
- `nsi` (Network Store Interface Service)
- `WdiServiceHost` (Windows Diagnostic Service Host Service)

**2nd svchost process**

- `CryptSvc` (Cryptographic Services)
- `Dnscache` (DNS Client)
- `LanmanWorkstation` (Workstation)
- `NlaSvc` (Network Location Awareness)

The memory leak seems to be syncronous between the two processes, they seem to take up equal amounts of space. I tried disabling the services related, but since they are quite important ones it is hard to do so without screwing the whole system. I also did not find the source by my tests.
I also tried flushing the DNS cache but this did nothing.

Does anyone have anything I can try except reboot Windows? The system is Windows 7 Professional 32 bit.

Comment: Try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) and see whether you still get the same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/583737/why-how-is-svchost-exe-using-all-of-my-memory/

Comment: I had a similar situation, and here is what I did to reduce the memory footprint of one instance of svchost.exe from 11GB to 0.1GB (the Win 7 machine has 12 GB RAM): Identified all services of the svchost.exe, and started to stop them one by one in alphabetic order.  I was unable to stop WsServiceHost, fdHost restarts immediately after stopping.  I watched the memory footprint after stopping each service. I saw it dropping only after stopping FontCache, and it dropped from 11 GB to 0.1GB.  Since this happened only once, I am not ready to make any conclusion.