# svchost.exe (netsvcs) high memory usage

Tags: windows-8, memory, windows-update, memory-leaks, svchost

OS: Windows 8 x64 (with all important updates installed)

Symptom: On occasion or when Windows Update window is opened, `svchost.exe (netsvcs)` memory usage would soar to as high as ~2GB.

An answer to a related question [Why/how is svchost.exe using 6.5GB of memory?](https://superuser.com/questions/583737/why-how-is-svchost-exe-using-6-5gb-of-memory) suggests hotfixes [`KB2847346`] and [`KB2950358`], but they appear to be for Windows 7.

I tried to update the Microsoft Update client through [`KB2887535`] from which I downloaded `Windows8-RT-KB2937636-x64`, but it prompted "The update is not applicable to your computer." (Did this mean I already had the latest version of client?)

I tried to run "Windows Update Diagnostic" and it did find some problems and fixed as shown below, but the issue remains the same.

[image: image identified]

Comment: have you made the upgrade to Windows 8.1?

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks for your concern. I have previously updated to Windows 8.1 and found that content arrangement in "This PC" changed unfavorably, including the merging of local HDDs with devices with removable storage and the placement of "Folders" in "This PC". In addition, the desktop background also changed without consent (and as it is Windows 8 built-in, I could not find it back on my computer), and an extra recovery partition was created from previous system partition, breaking the desired partition capacity, also without consent. These changes were user-unfriendly. Hence restored.

Comment: But you need to stay at 8.1. Starting Jan. 12th 2016 only 8.1 gets new updates. With OldNewExplorer you can tweak Explorer view: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-117/

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks. I would reconsider.

Comment: ok, so please update again to 8.1 to fix the issue and try OldNewExplroer to customize the Explorer the way you want. Otherwise you don't get new updates from Microsoft soon.

Comment: have you upgraded again to 8.1?

Comment: @magicandre1981: Yes. The issue is successfully solved. I currently feel OK about "This PC".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 8 (Build 9200) also suffers a high memory usage caused by Windows Update service. Because the issue is fixed with Windows 8.1, Microsoft suggests to update to Windows 8.1 to fix it.