# svchost.exe using 1GB of ram

Tags: windows-7, memory, svchost

so toray my computer was slowing down, so I checked the task manager to see what was going on. and svchost.exe was using about 1GB of ram. anyone have an idea to stop this?

os: Win 7 (non-genuine since I have used the same HDD in many PC's)

Comment: Probably Windows Update. Right click the svchost and click go to services to see what it's running.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why/how is svchost.exe using 6.5GB of memory?](http://superuser.com/q/583737) (not flagging as I have a dupe hammer)

Comment: The other question (so far) shows more useful information for narrowing it down, since many types of processes run under the blanket of svchost.exe.

Comment: this is a WU issue. Check the fixes in the duplicate link

Answer (score 0):

It's the windows update. You can stop this by disabling windows updates or by waiting for it to finish its job, which may take long.
[image]